# Remove quotation marks from variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to trim away the quotation marks from a PHP variable in CakePHP. I've tried `trim()`, `substr()`, `ereg_replace()`, and `str_replace()`, but nothing affects the quotation marks. When I use `substr` like this:

```
substr($comma_separated, 1, -1);
```

it removes the first and the last letter, but not the quotation marks. The string is

```
$comma_separated = "makamo66@hotmail.com','makamo66@gmail.com"
```

and this is an invalid email address for CakeEmail. I've also tried

```
$comma_separated = ereg_replace('"', "", $comma_separated);
```

and

```
$comma_separated = str_replace('"', '', $comma_separated);
```

I wasn't specific enough. It's the double quotation marks that I'm trying to remove. Not the single ones.

I've tried all this and they look like the normal quotation marks
    $comma_separated = ereg_replace('"', "", $comma_separated); //no change in output
    $comma_separated = str_replace('"', '', $comma_separated); //no change in output 
    $comma_separated = substr($comma_separated,1,-1); //outputs the last and first letter removed
    $comma_separated = trim($comma_separated,'"'); //no change in output

Comment: Don't use the `ereg_XXX` functions, they're deprecated. If you need to use regular expressions, use the PCRE functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have one string separated by `','`. A strange separator, but you can still [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) on that:

```
$addresses = explode("','", $comma_separated);
```

Comment: he doesn't want an array, he just wants a string with no quotes around each comma-separated value.

Answer (score 2):

Your `str_replace` isn't working because you are searching for the wrong quotation marks.  Your string has single quotes, so why are you searching for double quotes?

```
$comma_separated = str_replace("'", '', $comma_separated);
```

You can use this to remove *all* the quotes from the string.

Answer (score 0):

try this please :

```
$comma_separated = str_replace('\'', '', $comma_separated);
```

Comment: I've tried all this and they look like the normal quotation marks
$comma_separated = ereg_replace('"', "", $comma_separated); //no change in output
$comma_separated = str_replace('"', '', $comma_separated); //no change in output 
$comma_separated = substr($comma_separated,1,-1); //outputs the last and first letter removed
$comma_separated = trim($comma_separated,'"'); //no change in output